# Writing with numbers

Tags: python-2.7

I need to make a function that receives a string of numbers and the ouput is the letters that correspond to those numbers, like if you are sending a message on a cell phone. For example to get the letter 'A' the input should be '2', to get the letter 'B', the input should be '22', etc. For example:

```
>>>number_to_word('222 '233' '3'):
"CAFE"
```

The program needs to "go around" the number if the limit of the number is reached. For example, the letter 'A', can be these following inputs: '2', '2222','2222222', etc. Just like if your sending a text message on cell phone when you get pass 'C' ( which is'222' ) the program goes again to 'A', making '2222' it's key. Also, in the input, if the string is '233' the program must separate the different numbers, so this ('233') will be equal this ('2' '33')
I made a dictionary like this:

```
dic={'2':'A', '22':'B', '222':'C', '3':'D', '33':'E', '333':'F',..... etc}
```

But I don't know how to make the program "go around" if the input is '2222', and how do I take that number and assign it to the letter 'A'.
Feel free to ask any questions if you don't understand what I'm asking I would be glad to explain it with more detail. Thank you.

Comment: it seems that your dictionary is wrong: A does not map to the string `2`, but to the *pattern* `2[^2]$?`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to python and I don't understand that pattern, can you explain it in more detail please?

Comment: Google *"regular expressions"*

Comment: But if the dictionary uses that pattern what do I give as an argument? Because the purpose of the dictionary is that when the programm receives the string argument, it matches the string to the same key, receiving the value of that key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to give the desired result:

```
NUMBERS = {'2': 'A', '22': 'B', '222': 'C', '3': 'D', '33':'E', '333': 'F'}

def normalize_number(number):
    for item in number.split():
        if len(set(item)) == 1:
            yield item
        else:
            last = item[0]
            res = [last]
            for entry in item[1:]:
                if entry == last:
                    res.append(entry)
                else:
                    yield ''.join(res)
                    res = [entry]
                    last = entry
            yield ''.join(res)


def number_to_word(number):
    res = []
    for item in normalize_number(number):
        try:
            res.append(NUMBERS[item])
        except KeyError:
            if len(item) >= 4:
                end = len(item) % 3
                if end == 0:
                    end = 3
                res.append(NUMBERS[item[:end]]) 
    return ''.join(res)
```

Test it:

```
>>> number_to_word('222 2 333 33')
'CAFE'
>>> number_to_word('222 2 333 3333')
'CAFE'
>>> number_to_word('222 2 333 333333')
'CAFE'
>>> number_to_word('222 2333 3333')
'CAFE'
```

The function `normalize_number()` turns numbers that have different digits into multiple numbers with only the same digit:

```
>>> list(normalize_number('222 2 333 3333'))
['222', '2', '333', '3333']
>>> list(normalize_number('222 2333 3333'))
['222', '2', '333', '3333']
>>> list(normalize_number('222 2 333 53333'))
['222', '2', '333', '5', '3333']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will do my best to understand your code so that I fully understand how it works, once again, thank you.

Comment: I just noticed that if the input given is '2222' the letter of the output is 'B', when it should be 'A', how do I solve this? The same happens with other numbers, like '3333' gives 'E' when it should give 'D'.